# Principled BSDF (and other shaders) do not render textures with the Eevee engine

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render a texture that uses a Principled BSDF shader using Eevee, however nothing is shown on the render output

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I initially thought this might have something to do with my texture, so I used an RGB input and got exactly the same problem:

[image]

If I remove the Principled BSDF and link the picture direct to the Material Output it works fine:

[image]

This also applies to RGB inputs as well.

I've tried other shaders, and I'm having the exact same problems.

Oddly if I use the Cycles engine, the Principled BSDF (as well as all the other shaders) works fine:

[image]

**What I've done to try and solve the problem:**

- loaded factory settings
- selected the "repair" option on the Blender installer
- reinstalled Blender
- upgraded Blender to the latest version
- updated Windows and all my drivers to the latest version (including the GPU)
- tampered around with some of the settings (admittedly I don't know what I'm doing with most of them, so I could easily have missed it)

Could anyone please offer some help? It's been a few days and I'm getting a bit desparate.

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots  Here is my blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KlOxS9v1 I'mn not exactly sure how to pack it. Here is the texture via Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAVvNUXi0eWqvoge5CpTwYFxU8iOIzZx/view?usp=sharing I hope that will do

Comment: it works fine here, with Eevee or Cycles, so I don't know, I hope someone has an idea  :((

Comment: @moonboots I also had some files sent that had textures and they didn't show up either.  Could it be a broken GPU?  As I understand Eevee is GPU based.

Comment: @moonboots I solved it using this thread https://developer.blender.org/T83272
I Ran debug and got exactly the same output.  Turns out I had to downgrade my drivers to pre 20.11.2 and it worked fine.  Thank you for trying :D

Comment: oh ok, nice you've found the solution

Answer (score 1):

OK I eventually fixed it.

I ran debug mode and got the exact same error as on this thread posted this morning:

https://developer.blender.org/T83272

This is what they said:

> Next time, please follow the submission template and attach the debug
> log and system info as file.
>
> Please try to install a previous version of the graphics driver prior
> to Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2 Optional, 27.20.14501.18003 and
> report back if this resolves the issue.

I downgraded my graphics to 20.11.1 and it worked fine.